# Powershell script to create Azure Linux VM and setting FTP connection in it

Tags: linux, azure, ftp, sftp

I want to create Linux VM in Azure with some FTP port(21 and 22)open to create FTP connection? 
this is my script for creating VM:

This is new Edited Script

```
$SecurePassword =  $accPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $SecurePassword)

#Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $credential
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $credential


"Script is started"
## Global
$ResourceGroupName = "linux_vm_resource"
$Location = "Central India"

## Storage
$StorageName = "linuxvmstorageac"
$StorageType = "Standard_GRS"

## Network
$InterfaceName = "ServerInterface06"
$Subnet1Name = "Subnet1"
$VNetName = "linux_vm_vnet"
$VNetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/16"
$VNetSubnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/24"

## Compute
$VMName = "LinuxMigrateVm"
$VMSize = "Standard_F1S"
$OSDiskName = $VMName + "OSDisk1"

# Resource Group
$resourceGroup = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -ea SilentlyContinue
if(!$resourceGroup){
    New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location
}


# Storage
$StorageAccount = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageName
if(!$StorageAccount){
    $StorageAccount = New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageName -Type $StorageType -Location $Location
}

# Network
$PIp = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $InterfaceName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ea SilentlyContinue
if(!$PIp){
    $PIp = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $InterfaceName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -AllocationMethod Dynamic
}


## Create Network Security Group
$nsg = Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -Name "myNetworkSecurityGroup"-ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName 
if(!$nsg){

    $httprule1 = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "default-allow-ssh" `
        -Description "Allow HTTP" -Access "Allow" -Protocol "TCP" -Direction "Inbound" `
        -Priority "1000" -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * `
        -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 22

    $httprule2 = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "ftp_client" `
        -Description "Allow HTTP" -Access "Allow" -Protocol "TCP" -Direction "Inbound" `
        -Priority "1010" -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * `
        -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 21

    $httprule3 = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "all" `
        -Description "Allow HTTP" -Access "Allow" -Protocol "TCP" -Direction "Outbound" `
        -Priority "100" -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * `
        -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 21

    $httprule4 = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "ssh" `
        -Description "Allow HTTP" -Access "Allow" -Protocol "TCP" -Direction "Outbound" `
        -Priority "110" -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * `
        -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 22

    $nsg = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
        -Location $Location -Name "myNetworkSecurityGroup" -SecurityRules $httprule1,$httprule2,$httprule3,$httprule4  
}


$SubnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $Subnet1Name -AddressPrefix $VNetSubnetAddressPrefix -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg


$VNet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VNetName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName 
if(!$VNet){
    $VNet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VNetName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -AddressPrefix $VNetAddressPrefix -Subnet $SubnetConfig

}

$Interface = Get-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $InterfaceName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
if(!$Interface){      
    $Interface = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $InterfaceName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -SubnetId $VNet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $PIp.Id
}


# Compute

## Setup local VM object

$VirtualMachine = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $VMSize
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $VirtualMachine -Linux -ComputerName $VMName -Credential $Credential 
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $VirtualMachine -PublisherName "Canonical" -Offer "UbuntuServer" -Skus "16.10" -Version "latest" 

$VirtualMachine = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $Interface.Id
$OSDiskUri = $StorageAccount.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob.ToString() + "vhds/" + $OSDiskName + ".vhd"
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -Name $OSDiskName -VhdUri $OSDiskUri -CreateOption FromImage

## Create the VM in Azure
$vM = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
if(!$vM){
    $vM = New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -VM $VirtualMachine
}
```

Script is working but it creates the VM and nsg seperately. Any suggestion to attach the nsg with the VM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the VM,we can add ports to NSG inbound rules via **Azure portal**.
More information about how to add ports to NSG's inbound rules, refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-nsg-arm-pportal#create-rules-in-an-existing-nsg).

[image]

If you haven't create this VM, you can add the NSG's configuration to this PowerShell script, Then deploy it. More information about PowerSehll to set NSG, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-powershell).

For example:

```
$FTPrule = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name "myNetworkSecurityGroupRule" `
    -Description "Allow port 21" -Access "Allow" -Protocol "Tcp" -Direction "Inbound" `
    -Priority "100" -SourceAddressPrefix "Internet" -SourcePortRange * `
    -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 21
```

Comment: Let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply, I'll follow this. One more thing, In the script i've written some static values like $locationName and VMImage description -Skus and -version which sometimes giving error. Is there any solution for this too So that I dont have to provide this much details.

Comment: Do you mean you want to define Skus and Version first? if yes, we can define them first, for example, $skus="15.10" $offer="UbuntuServer" then we can use in the next script: $VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $VirtualMachine -PublisherName "Canonical" -Offer $offer -Skus $skus -Version "latest"

Comment: @Rishabh we can use powershell to get the information about the image, for example, we can use Get-AzureRmVMImageSku -Location "east us" -PublisherName "SUSE" -Offer "SLES" . to get image offfer use Get-AzureRmVMImageOffer. to get image publisher: Get-AzureRmVMImagePublisher

Comment: @Rishabh Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: I've changed the script, it is now creating the VM but network_security_group is created seperately, not attached with the created VM. any assistence?

Comment: @Rishabh you are right, NSG create after Vnet complete, so we can add NSG script after the Vnet script. After Vnet complete, the NSG can associate the vnet.

Comment: @Rishabh  after Vnet created, then use set-azurermvirtualnetwork to associate the NSG settings.

Comment: @Rishabh if it helps, please mark it as an answer, thanks.

Comment: Can u help me for one more thing? actually i want to change the username and password for the above created vm. But its not changing I have tried this with azure portal as well but its giving error. Do you have any solution for this, that works with powershell too

Comment: Please refer to this link,https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-vmaccess-extension-to-reset-login-credentials-for-linux-vm/

Comment: @ Jason Ye , Can u please suggest any solution for this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266611/aws-ec2-migration-to-azure-vm-using-nodsjs-code